# How many possibilities for a $12$ digit binary number with six $1$s and six $0$s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binary

I am trying to figure out how many possibilities there is to build a $12$-digit binary number with six $1$s and six $0$s.

One example would be: $111111000000$

Comment: Combinatorics is your friend.

Comment: Select the (6) places you want 1's to be, and other 6 places are filled with 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  The leading digit must be a $1$, for otherwise the number would have fewer than $12$ digits.  That leaves you with eleven positions to fill with five $1$s and six $0$s.  The number is completely determined by choosing which five of the remaining $11$ positions will be filled with $1$s.  The number of ways a subset of $k$ elements can be selected from a set with $n$ elements is 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
where $n!$ is the product of the first $n$ positive integers if $n$ is positive and $0! = 1$.